# CasperJS test coverage

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, casperjs

Is it possible to get test coverage for casperJS tests? (Like istanbul or mocha-lcov).
I googled a lot and could not find any official or unofficial coverage tool.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? There is an implicit test coverage integrated by passing the number of expected tests into `casper.test.begin`. Do you mean coverage of the tested website? If yes, then this has nothing to do with casperjs and is also **off-topic**, because you want a tool recommendation. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) point 4.

Answer (score -1):

Look at this casper issue: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/153
Currently Istanbul is recommended: https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul-middleware

Comment: Please flesh out your answer a bit more. This looks more like a link-only answer.