# Is there a way to get _client-side_ test coverage in CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, testing, backbone.js, casperjs

I have a very frontend-heavy application, built in Backbone, and I would like to replace messy dirty unit tests that we wrote to tests view behaviour with CasperJS functional tests.

I would like to have a report which shows me how much of my **client-side** code has been actually covered when running my functional tests. Is there a way to do this?

The only thing I found was [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25229613/casperjs-test-coverage), which points to coverage for **server-side** code.

I am currently using Istanbul for coverage reports on my Jasmine unit-tests, so bonus points for anyone who can come up with a way to combine jasmine unit-test coverage with the CasperJS coverage in istanbul.

Comment: Probably not or at least not easily and not for any situation.

Comment: If you're able to change the page you're testing, then you can use PhantomJS to do this: in conjunction with JSCoverage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jscoverage+phantomjs